# VMware VM with CentOS latest too slow while try to access PHP sites through browser

Tags: centos, windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a instance of VMware Workstation 10.0.1 running in my PC. My PC has this configuration:

```
Proccessor: Core i5 3120M
Memory: 3992 MB
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit 6.1.7601, Service Pack 1
```

The image below shows how I configured my network:

[image: Virtual Network Configuration]

And this other image shows how I setup my VM properties for network:

[image: Virtual Machine Properties]

I have this entries in the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
192.168.3.137   devserver
192.168.3.137   wuelto.com
```

But any time I load kraken.devserver it takes one minute or more to load complete. All the resources is local on that VM so the site didn't look for any outside VM, where is the bottlenecks? Is my configuration wrong at some part? This other image show load time for this test site (notice the load time at the end), any advice?

[image: Load Times]

**Some changes at configuration**

Following the recommendations from here I started to setup vCPU and Cores, since this is my guest configuration:

```
Proccessor: Core i5 3120M
Memory: 3992 MB
```

What should be the right configuration for this one? (see image below)

[image: VMware Configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is not a networking issue. You may want to consider re-configuring your VM to use all cores of your processor, and increase memory to 1GB. I have personally experienced this issue and found some systems where the selection of a single core for the VM will cause the VM to stutter network and other system functions to the point where they are perceived to be running slow.

Also, you may want to confirm you have  any Hyper-V features enabled in your host system's BIOS.

Comment: I added some extra info, please take a look

Comment: Well I leave vCPU configuration as image shows and slowness still I don't know where the problem is? Services running? I have Apache + PHP + MySQL + PostgreSQL an usual CentOS services

Comment: Hmm... I did a bit of reading and you might want to look over this KB article. While it mentions Server 2008, 2008 and Windows 7 supposed to be API/code compatible, so these suggestions should be applicable. Note the Power Plan configuration info as that's what caught my eye. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2008925   -- Also, I'd still bump the Guest OS RAM to 1GB for best performance while working this out.

Comment: Thanks for your support I change plan settings from `Balanced` to `High Perfomance` and I notice a little improve but times are not right for me, maybe some Apache configuration, I'll open another post asking for this part

Comment: No problem. FWIW, I sincerely doubt this is anything to do with your LAMP configuration. Problems like this are 99% due to Host configuration issues. If making that Windows OS level power plan change offered some improvement, you may way to turn off the ACPI features in your BIOS and evaluate the effect.